# Bigquery type cast on JOIN Clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to join two tables on two columns

```
 -- query to join two tables
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [raw.raw_sales] AS game_records
JOIN
  [facebook_aggregate.avg_aggregate] AS avg_aggregate
ON
  (game_records.Away_team = avg_aggregate.team_name)
  AND (game_records.game_date = avg_aggregate.time_update)
```

it gives me this error `Error: 10.30 - 10.56: Timestamp literal or explicit conversion to timestamp is required.` because `game_records.game_date` is type STRING and `avg_aggregate.time_update` is type DATE.

but if I do the conversion within the JOIN..ON.. clause

```
 -- query to join two tables
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [raw.raw_sales] AS game_records
JOIN
  [facebook_aggregate.avg_aggregate] AS avg_aggregate
ON
  (game_records.Away_team = avg_aggregate.team_name)
  AND (DATE(game_records.game_date) = DATE(avg_aggregate.time_update))
```

It gives me this error:
`Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. .`

Is there any way to do this without creating an intermediate table? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options"). You shouldn't need to do anything aside from remove the brackets around the table names:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  raw.raw_sales AS game_records
JOIN
  facebook_aggregate.avg_aggregate AS avg_aggregate
ON
  game_records.Away_team = avg_aggregate.team_name
  AND game_records.game_date = avg_aggregate.time_update;
```

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)) does not have this limitation for ON clause. Try running your query in Standard SQL.
As Elliott mentioned  - make sure you are not using square brackets around tables references. In Standard SQL - when you need to escape special chars - yo should use back-ticks

Also check [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql) if you will follow above direction